# Zbar in CPP Project libiconv.lib not found

Tags: c++, windows-10, visual-studio-2017, 64-bit, zbar

Hello I try to integrate Zbar 64bit version into my visual studio cpp project. I downloaded the build from https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/ZBarWin64 and I set up my IncludePath to both include and \zbar\include also included both libs lib + zbar\lib-64. The linker was also set to 64 version but now I'm getting an error.

> The code execution cannot proceed because libiconv.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

I already set the linker and lib path to the folder where the dll is. But still getting the error.

Any suggestions?

Kind regards

Max

Answer (score 0):

Added `ZBarWin64-master\zbar\libiconv` to system variables **PATH**.
Added `ZBarWin64-master\zbar\libiconv\dll_x64` to system variables **PATH**.

Don't know what fixed it, but now it is running like a charm :)